# Connect to Teradata from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, teradata, provider

Under the ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit), I have setup a User Data Source for connecting to a Teradata server.  In Teradata SQL Assistant, I am able to connect to the Teradata server using this ODBC configuration.

We have an existing VB.net application through which we want to connect to the Teradata server.  Given below is the VB.net code to connect to the Teradata database

```
Import System.Data.OldDB

Module Utilities
    Public Sub connectToDB()
        Dim sconnect As String
        Dim CONN As OleDbConnection

        Try
            If CONN IsNot Nothing Then
                If CONN.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    CONN.Close()
            End If

            CONN = Nothing

            CONN = New OleDbConnection
            sconnect = "Provider=TeraData_Connection;Data Source=XXXPROD.UNIX.XXX; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx; Session Mode=ANSI;"
            CONN.ConnectionString = sconnect

            CONN.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Cannot open connection ! " & ex.Message,, "ERROR")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

On calling the connectToDB() called the following error message is shown

> Cannot open connection ! The 'TeraData_Connection' provider is not
>   registered on the local machine.

Is this error coming because the OLE DB driver for Teradata is not installed in my windows 10 machine or anything else?

How do I find out whether the OLE DB driver is installed on my machine?

Is there any other way to connect to Teradata from vb.net?

Is there anything else I need to check?

Comment: Check the bit-ness of your app.  Could be it's trying to use the 32bit instead of the 64bit driver for teradata which you may not have installed

Comment: There is no *TeraData_Connection* provider. If you are intending to use the ODBC driver then the Provider can be defaulted (or explicitly specified as MSDASQL).Then either use DSN=*your-predefined-data-source-name* or Driver=*the-Teradata-ODBC-driver-name*  (for "DSN-less" connection).

Comment: What in the world is OldDB that you are importing?

Comment: There is in fact a .net provider for Teradata which will undoubtedly give you better results.

Comment: @Mary, OldDb is a misspelled OleDB.

Answer (score 0):

Source file: conn.aspx

```
   <%
   Dim connStr = _
     "Driver=Teradata;DBCNAME=<ODBC DSN Name>;Database=Dbc;UID=<Username>;PWD=<password>;"
   Dim conn As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(connStr)

   conn.open()
   conn.close()
   %>
```

Source file: conn.vbs

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

connStr = _
  "Driver=Teradata;DBCNAME=<ODBC DSN Name>;Database=Dbc;UID=<Username>;PWD=<password>;"

conn.open( connStr )
MsgBox("Opened")
conn.close()
```

Comment: Note that prior to TTU 16.00 the name of the ODBC driver was simply *Teradata* but current versions are named *Teradata Database ODBC Driver xx.yy* where *xx.yy* represents the installed version.

Comment: Confirmed: 15.10 client uses "Teradata" as a provider, refuses the name on 16.20, but accepts Fred's naming convention ("Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20").